# How to let aspectj worked in webtestclient?

Tags: spring, aspectj, spock, spring-webflux

I have some apis implements by spring webflux. Now i need to write some UT to test it. I write the UT code by spock, and create a mock server by the method WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction. It worked as well. But  i found that i have an ParaCheckAspect to check the api's parameters, it doesn't work because I have not created Spring IOC . I have to look the WebTestClient apis, it not has any api to register my ParaCheckAspect. Please tell me if you know any way to resolve it.

I have look the spring document https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#webtestclient. It not has effective info for this.

```java
/**
 * check Parameters is validate
 */
@Aspect
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ParaCheckAspect {

    @Around("execution (* com.winston.springboot.handler..*(..))")
    public Object validate(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        for (int i = 0; i < point.getArgs().length; i++) {
            if (point.getArgs()[i] instanceof Mono) {
                point.getArgs()[i] = ((Mono<?>) point.getArgs()[i])
                    .doOnNext(this::check)
                    .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,e.getMessage())));
            } else if (point.getArgs()[i] instanceof Flux) {
                point.getArgs()[i] = ((Flux<?>) point.getArgs()[i])
                    .doOnNext(this::check)
                  .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,e.getMessage())));
            }
        }
        return point.proceed(point.getArgs());
    }
    private void check(Object obj) {
        //some validator code

    }
}
```

```
import com.winston.springboot.config.routers.UserRouter
import com.winston.springboot.entity.User
import com.winston.springboot.handler.UserHandler
import org.mockito.InjectMocks
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class UserHandlerSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared
    WebTestClient testClient

    @InjectMocks
    UserHandler userHandler

    void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        def function = routeFunction()
        def routeFunctionSpec = WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(function)
        testClient = routeFunctionSpec
                .configureClient()
                .baseUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8089")
                .build()
    }

    def 'test userSave'() {
        given:
        User user = User.builder().name("lina").age(10).build()
        when:
        testClient.post().uri("/user")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(user))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk()
                .expectBody(User.class)
                .returnResult();
        then:
        noExceptionThrown();
    }

    def routeFunction() {
      return  new UserRouter().userRouterFunction(userHandler);
    }

}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you mix three different test tools from Spring, Spock and Mockito and why for example you don't just create your mocks or stubs the Spock way instead of making it complicated and let Mockito inject them? Also, why is the test client a `@Shared` variable if it gets initialised for each feature method in `setup()` anyway? Furthermore, the sample code uses several imports of classes not shown here, so nobody can compile and run your test in order to reproduce your problem. Maybe you want to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), possibly in GitHub.

Comment: Spring AOP is a blocking and cannot be used by just "casting" things to fluxes and monos and hope it will work with spring webflux. None of your code will work, since noone is subscribing to any of your fluxes. You cannot use Spring AOP with webflux if you don't know what you are doing. So you should do your checks some other way.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for your suggestion. I have push my code to GitHub. The link is :https://github.com/winston9527/webtestclient-example.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Thanks for your attention. The spring AOP is work well in webflux . But i don't how to use it in my UT code. Because i couldn't fond an api to invoke it in the UT.

Comment: ofc it works well because you are doing some ugly castings, and returning an `Object` there are a lot better ways of doing validation checks then using Aspects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using spring, you should include the `spock-spring` module, this adds spring support to your `Specification`. Then you need to use `@SpringBootTest` or a similar spring annotation, e.g. `@WebFluxTest`, and inject your handlers. This ways spring creates the instances and applies the AOP interceptors.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Finally, I have include ```spock-spring``` module to my project. and use ```WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext``` instead of ```WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction```

Comment: `@WebFluxTest` should already provide a pre-configured `WebTestClient` just inject it via `@Autowired`

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer (yet), for the moment only a way to communicate with the OP because I need space to post code and callstacks, which is impossible in a comment.*

**Disclaimer:** I never used Gradle (only Maven) and know zero about Webflux. But a few things I can say:

- When cloning your project the first thing I noticed was that you forgot `apply plugin: "groovy"` in *build.gradle*. Without it your Spock test is not even compiled and run.
- After adding the Groovy plugin, running the test yields the following execption:

```
Method org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(Lorg/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/RouterFunction;)Lorg/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Method org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(Lorg/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/RouterFunction;)Lorg/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/
    at com.winston.webflux.UserHandlerSpec.setup(UserHandlerSpec.groovy:25)

com.winston.webflux.UserHandlerSpec > test userSave FAILED
    java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError at UserHandlerSpec.groovy:25
```

Is this your problem? You never said what problem you actually have, only that "AspectJ" (you really mean Spring AOP) does not work in your test.

There also is a sample application. I can start it, but what do I need to do to make the aspect kick in? Sorry, I am really not a Spring guy, I am just kind of an AOP expert and know about Spock, too. So please help me understand the problem first. If I open http://localhost:8080/user/ in the browser I just get a "Whitelabel Error Page" without any log output on the console.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is my first time ask a question at stackoverflow. And my mother language isn’t Enginsh, so  maybe i have not clear describe the  question. Thank you again for you patience.
This application suppled an api that only support http post request. 
URL:http://127.0.0.1:8080/user .
Parameter:{"name":"tony","age":21}
I test this api by PostMan.

Comment: This question is that when i invoke this api by PostMan the ParaCheckAspect will be invoked and print “ParaCheckAspect.check has been invoked” on the  console. Now i invoke this api by  WebTestClient in UT code, the ParaCheckAspect had not invoked.  I haven’t found an api to register ParaCheckAspect. I don't know if this clarifies my question.

Comment: Well, if I run the application I can use `curl -s -X POST -d '{"name":"tony","age":21}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/user/`, get a valid result and see the aspect invoked. So far, so good. So whoever wants to help you and knows Spring WebClient, just needs to fix the Gradle definition like I said and then find out about the test error I posted above. Is that error what you are seeing too? I have no idea how to solve that, just wanted to guide you to make the problem reproducible first.